# serverless framework Choice Activity with Logical Operators

Tags: npm, serverless

A simple Choice Activity in serverless.yml file would be

```
CheckActionType:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
            - Variable: "$.results.ACTION"
              StringEquals: "CREATED"
              Next: CreateOrderTask
```

but how would we implement a logical Operator in Choice Task ( for example for the given ASL, if anybody can give me corresponding serverless.yml file)

```
"CheckActionType": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.results.ACTION",
              "StringEquals": "CREATED"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.results.BUSINESS",
              "StringEquals": "Payroll"
            }
          ],
          "Next": "CreateOrderTask"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because I see there is an indentation issue in your yml. You need one more space added to the Choices themseves:

```
CheckActionType:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: "$.results.ACTION"
                StringEquals: "CREATED"
                Next: CreateOrderTask
```

The - make these items array elements. To match the example you have above is like:

```
CheckActionType: 
  Type: Choice
  Choices: 
    - And: 
       - Variable: "$.results.ACTION"
         StringEquals: "CREATED"
       - Variable: "$.results.BUSINESS"
         StringEquals: "Payroll"
    - Next: "CreateOrderTask"
```

Comment: Worked, Except had to take out hyphen before Next